# Different authentication methods for multiple site collections

Tags: sharepoint-server, authentication

We have an SharePoint 2013 On-Premise farm with a single application that contains multiple site collections. There is a new requirement that all site collections should allow anonymous authentication except one which should only be accessible using forms-based authentication. Client is very adamant to keep existing URL structure.
So the URL structure should be like this:

Anonymous:

```
http://www.appname.com/sites/siteA

----------------------------/siteB

----------------------------/siteC
```

Forms-based:

```
http://www.appname.com/sites/siteD
```

Is it possible? If I extend the web application with different authentication method then the URL structure will change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. First you enable anonymous access at the web application level (affecting all site collections on that web application). Then for the specific site collection that you do not want anonymous access to, under the site collection's site settings you disable it by breaking it's inheritance of the parent web application's settings. You can do this for lists too, i.e break inheritance in the permissions page and then remove the 'anonymous users' entries.

Topical SO question:

- [Disabling Anonymous Access](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62358/disabling-anonymous-access)

Further refernces:

- http://www.topsharepoint.com/enable-anonymous-access-in-sharepoint-2010
- https://bernado-nguyen-hoan.com/2014/06/18/enabledisable-anonymous-access-for-selected-pages-in-sharepoint/

Answer (score 0):

Enable both Anoymous and form based authentication on web application.

Grant permissions to only Anonymours on one site sollection and to FBA users on the other site collection.

Hope it helps

Comment: oops  :( @Anders had already suggested the option